# Riding platform Phaser3

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-physics, phaser-framework

in my 2D game I have 1 character and a platform that moves left and right with tweens. I created this platform as an object in tiledmapeditor and it spawns by giving texture.
When my character comes on this platform, I want it to move with the platform. How do I do this.

This is my MovementPlatform.ts ;

```
    import {
  ActorProps,
  ICollectable,
  IDieable,
  IMoveable,
} from "@games/common/interfaces";
import { Actor } from "@games/common/objects";

export default class MovementPlatform
  extends Actor
  implements IMoveable, IDieable, ICollectable {
  declare body: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body;
  declare startX;
  constructor(props: ActorProps) {
    super(props);
    this.scene.physics.add.existing(this);
    this.body.setAllowGravity(false);
    this.body.immovable = true;
    this.startX = this.x;

    this.move();
  }

  update(...args: any[]): void { }

  die(): void { }

  move(): void {
    this.scene.tweens.add({
      targets: this,
      x: this.startX + 200,
      duration: 1000,
      yoyo: true,
      repeat: -1,
    });
  }

  collect(...props: any[]): void { }
}
```

This is where spawning movementPlatform from tiledmapeditör(this is already working correctly)

```
    private spawnMovementPlatform() {
  const movementPlatformTiles = getObjectsByType(
    "movementPlatform",
    this.map
  );

  movementPlatformTiles.forEach((el: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tile, i: number) => {
    const movementplatform = new MovementPlatform({
      key: `movementPlatform-${this.movements.length}`,
      scene: this,
      texture: "movementPlatform",
      x: el.x,
      y: el.y + 200,
    }).setDepth(3);

    this.movements.push(movementplatform);
  });
}
```

and I don't know if I need to check my collider and do it this way here or if I need to process in movementPaltform.ts. I tried a lot of things but it didn't work.

```
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.movements, () => {});
```

Comment: Does my answer explain the issue you are having? Or do you need some more details?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your code does, or what you have tried, but based on the mentioned details. I must assume, you would only need to call the `move` function on a collision (I would add a property `isMoving` to the class `MovementPlatform` just to be on the save side)

**So basically:**

```
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.movements, (player: any, platform:any) => {
    if(!platform.isMoving){
        platform.isMoving = true;
        platform.move();  
    }
});
```

**Update:**
The Problem is I didn't see you are moving the `x` and `y` position of the platform, if you use the physics functions like `setVelocity`, the "sticky" feature should work.

**Short example:**
Left side platform, the position is altered with a tween, similar to your code.
On the right side, I'm using the velocity function to move the platform *(this works)*.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update,
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Left move position, Right using physics')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let p1 = this.physics.add.existing(this.add.rectangle(200, 20, 10, 10, 0xff0000));
    
     let p2 = this.physics.add.existing(this.add.rectangle(400, 20, 10, 10, 0xff0000));
     let floor1StartX = 200;
     let floor1 = this.physics.add.existing(this.add.rectangle(floor1StartX, 80, 100, 10, 0x0000ff));
     floor1.body.setAllowGravity(false);
     floor1.body.setImmovable(true);     

     let floor2 = this.physics.add.existing(this.add.rectangle(400, 80, 100, 10, 0x0000ff))
     floor2.body.setAllowGravity(false);
     floor2.body.setImmovable(true);
     
     this.floor2 = floor2;

     this.physics.add.collider(p1, floor1);
     this.physics.add.collider(p2, floor2);
     
     this.tweens.add({
      targets: floor1,
      x: floor1StartX + 50,
      duration: 1000,
      yoyo: true,
      repeat: -1,
    });
}

function update(){
    if (this.floor2.x >= 400)
    {
        this.floor2.body.setVelocityX(-50);
    }
    else if (this.floor2.x <= 350)
    {
        this.floor2.body.setVelocityX(50);
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no problem with the move() function of the platform, it is already working. Here's what I'm trying to do in summary; When the player comes on the platform, I want it to move with the platform, I think it's called sticky

Comment: @yunusemreagdin sorry I didn't see that, I updated my answer explaining the issue.